# Serialization Cryptography Error

Tags: vb.net, serialization, visual-studio-2012, cryptography, deserialization

I am having trouble using encryption with serialization when deserializing an object.

This is the error:

> Failed to deserialize. Reason: End of Stream encountered before parsing was completed

Here is my code:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary
Imports System.Text

Module TestModEncryption

Public Sub SaveEncryptedObjectToFile(FileName As String, Item As Object)
    Dim fs As FileStream
    Dim encryptor As CryptoStream

    Dim formatter As New BinaryFormatter

    Dim password As String = "MyPassword"
    Dim salt As String = "InitialVector123"

    Dim AES As AesManaged = New AesManaged
    AES.Padding = PaddingMode.None
    AES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC

    Dim HashAlgorithm As String = "SHA1" 'Can be SHA1 or MD5
    Dim PasswordIterations As Integer = 2
    Dim InitialVector As String = "InitialVector123" 'This should be a string of 16 ASCII characters.
    Dim KeySize As Integer = 256 'Can be 128, 192, or 256.

    Dim InitialVectorBytes As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(InitialVector)
    Dim SaltValueBytes As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(salt)
    Dim DerivedPassword As New Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, SaltValueBytes, PasswordIterations)
    Dim KeyBytes As Byte() = DerivedPassword.GetBytes(CInt(KeySize / 8))

    Dim encryptTransf As ICryptoTransform = AES.CreateEncryptor(KeyBytes, InitialVectorBytes)

    fs = New FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Create)
    encryptor = New CryptoStream(fs, encryptTransf, CryptoStreamMode.Write)

    Try
        formatter.Serialize(encryptor, Item)
    Catch e As SerializationException
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to serialize. Reason: " & e.Message)
        Throw
    Finally
        fs.Close()
    End Try
End Sub

Public Function OpenEncryptedObjectFromFile(FileName As String) As Object
    Dim fs As New FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open)
    Dim decryptor As CryptoStream

    Dim ItemToReturn As New Object

    Dim password As String = "MyPassword"
    Dim salt As String = "InitialVector123"

    Dim AES As AesManaged = New AesManaged
    AES.Padding = PaddingMode.None
    AES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC

    Dim HashAlgorithm As String = "SHA1" 'Can be SHA1 or MD5
    Dim PasswordIterations As Integer = 2
    Dim InitialVector As String = "InitialVector123" 'This should be a string of 16 ASCII characters.
    Dim KeySize As Integer = 256 'Can be 128, 192, or 256.

    Dim InitialVectorBytes As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(InitialVector)
    Dim SaltValueBytes As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(salt)
    Dim DerivedPassword As New Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, SaltValueBytes, PasswordIterations)
    Dim KeyBytes As Byte() = DerivedPassword.GetBytes(CInt(KeySize / 8))

    Dim decryptTrans As ICryptoTransform = AES.CreateDecryptor(KeyBytes, InitialVectorBytes)

    Try
        Dim formatter As New BinaryFormatter

        decryptor = New CryptoStream(fs, decryptTrans, CryptoStreamMode.Read)
        ItemToReturn = DirectCast(formatter.Deserialize(decryptor), Object)
        Return ItemToReturn
    Catch e As SerializationException
        MsgBox("Failed to deserialize. Reason: " & e.Message)
        Return Nothing
        'Throw
    Finally
        fs.Close()
    End Try
End Function

End Module
```

Comment: `This should be a string of 16 ASCII characters`? No. It should be an unpredictable and unique string of bytes, preferably from a secure random number generator, and it should be different every time the function is called. Using two iterations with PBKDF2 is totally bogus, and in fact, using PBKDF2 at all in this case is totally bogus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crypto is somewhat complex.  First get the crypto working, just the crypto.  Start with a piece of text: "I wandered lonely as an armadillo."  Use your code to encrypt and decrypt that text, forgetting about the serialization.  When that is working correctly then, and only then, use your working crypto code to encrypt/decrypt the serialized object.

Have you successfully serialized/deserialized your object without any encryption?

On a brief glance, you need to set padding to PKCS#7 (aka PKCS#5).  Your `PaddingMode.None` may be what is causing the problem.  Without padding your final block may not be being processed correctly.  Obviously you need to use the same padding for both encryption and decryption.